# Oracle SQL data input issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have just created a new database and I'm at the stage now where I am looking to input my data. I've created the tables and the constraints work fine, and I have inserted 1 row successfully. However when running the query `select * from mytable;` it returns the table once for every field.

I have spent the past 2 hours researching why but cant find anything. Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do u mean by "it returns the table once for every field" ?

Comment: Basically i have created a table with 10 column headers. I have then created a script to insert data. When i view my table it returns the table 10 times, rather than once with all the data in.

Comment: post sample insert scripts

Comment: What tool are you using to query the database? Is it SQL*Plus?

Comment: insert into gh_CUSTOMER(cust_firstName,cust_surname,Cust_house,Cust_addr1,Cust_addr2,Cust_town,Cust_city,Cust_pc,Cust_phone,Cust_fax,Cust_email,Cust_creditlimit,Cust_optout,Cust_notes,cust_id) values('Gavin','Howard',1,'1 Brown crescent','Eighton Banks','Gateshead','Newcastle','NE97EX','01914602096','01914602091','Gavinhoward@me.com',1,'y','no notes',1);

Comment: Does `set linesize <something big>` or `set wrap off` help? It's a little unclear what you're seeing... reducing the displayed column width might help, but only if the columns are defined much larger than required for the date they hold.

Comment: @GavinHoward, please post new code as an edit to your original question - code in a comment is difficult to read and nearly impossible to format.

Comment: Here is one way to check that there is only one row in your table: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gh_customer;`. My guess is that this is just a SQL*Plus formatting issue.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you're using SQL*Plus and that the columns in your table are rather wide (say `varchar2(1000)` for example).

In  this scenario, SQL*Plus's width is to small to horizontally display multiple columns, hence it displays them vertically.

You could get around this with

```
select
  substr(col1, 1, 20) col1_,
  substr(col2, 1, 20) col2_
  ...
from
  table;
```

or, when still in SQL*Plus, with a [column format](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_six.htm#CHDBEAAB) command:

```
column format col1 a20
column format col2 a20
...
select * from table;
```